# Live Transcription in a GUI with Python

Tags: python, user-interface, speech-recognition, real-time, speech-to-text

How to create a script in Python that transcribes the speech, i.e. speech to text (STT), coming from my microphone in real-time and prints the text on a GUI?

Some particularities:

- the STT engine (provider) has to be Google Cloud or Azure;
- I'm using a laptop and the microphone could be the embedded or the headphone;
- the printing could be word by word, as the text is coming back from the engine (not once the sentence is completed and then print it all);
- a button to start, stop and clean the GUI is needed, i.e. keys from the keyboard;
- once at stand-by, a button to change the language, if they do have not automatic language recognition.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.